# How to parce by jsoup for specific element from div?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I have a website with titles ".entry-title" in div "td_module_5".

I writed a code for parcing by jsoup ".entry-title", but this "entry-title" are contained in another div, for example "td_mega_menu".

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(blogUrl).get();
title = doc.select(".entry-title");
titleList.clear();
for (Element titles : title) {
titleList.add(titles.text());
}
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How to parce by jsoup ".entry-title" only from div "td_module_5"?

Example html-code:

```
<div class="td_module_5 td_module_wrap td-animation-stack" >
            <div class="td-module-image td-module-image-float">
                <div class="td-module-thumb"><a class="td-admin-edit" href="https://unspecific.ru/wp-admin/post.php?post=7148&amp;action=edit">edit</a><a href="https://unspecific.ru/bakteriofagi-smogut-vylechit-nyak-i-bk/" rel="bookmark" title="Бактериофаги смогут вылечить НЯК и БК?"><img width="260" height="195" class="entry-thumb" src="https://unspecific.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/bacf-260x195.jpg" srcset="https://unspecific.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/bacf-260x195.jpg 260w, https://unspecific.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/bacf-300x225.jpg 300w, https://unspecific.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/bacf-80x60.jpg 80w, https://unspecific.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/bacf-245x184.jpg 245w, https://unspecific.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/bacf.jpg 640w" sizes="(max-width: 260px) 100vw, 260px" alt="Бактериофаг и бактерия" title="Бактериофаги смогут вылечить НЯК и БК?"/></a></div>            </div>

            <div class="td-item-details td-category-small">
                <a href="https://unspecific.ru/category/news/" class="td-post-category">Новости в лечении ВЗК</a>                
                <h3 class="entry-title td-module-title"><a href="https://unspecific.ru/bakteriofagi-smogut-vylechit-nyak-i-bk/" rel="bookmark" title="Бактериофаги смогут вылечить НЯК и БК?">Бактериофаги смогут вылечить НЯК и БК?</a></h3>
```

Comment: Can you provide the part of html you tried to parse?

Comment: Added in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below css path selector :

```
    Element title = doc.select("div > .entry-title").first();
    System.out.println(title.text());
```

Or if you want to find all titles:

```
    Elements titles = doc.select("div > .entry-title");

    for (Element title: titles) {
        System.out.println(title.text());
    }
```

In your case because you want to select under specific div with specific css class you should use below:

```
    Elements titles = doc.select("div.td_module_5.td_module_wrap.td-animation-stack > div > .entry-title");

    for (Element title: titles) {
        System.out.println(title.text());
    }
```

The output is :

```
Бактериофаги смогут вылечить НЯК и БК?
```

Comment: For your second answer - code find all of .entry-title from all div's, not only for td_module_5.

Comment: I edited my answer, added selector for class td_module_5

Comment: I'm glad to help you

Comment: You can just do: `doc.select(".td_module_5 .entry-title")`